# Drop a column while reading mutliple files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I will like to drop column 'grade'

File 1:

```
 Name  Grade  School  Class  .... ... ...
```

File 2:

```
Name  School  Class  .... ... ...
```

This is my code:

```
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file, header=0)
    df = df.drop(['Grade'],axis=1)
```

However the error is 'labels grade not contained in axis'

Comment: Use an if statement, like `if 'Grade' in df.columns: df = df.drop(['Grade'],axis=1)`

Comment: have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116091/pandas-dataframe-drop-valueerror-labels-id-not-contained-in-axis